# Interaction between forms in WinForms application, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

guys!
I've got 2 forms in application - working form (frmMain) and form of settings (frmSettings).
There are two buttons on frmSettings - Save and Cancel. In frmMain I use the following approach to show the frmSettings:

```
 private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmSettings = new SettingsForm();
            frmSettings.ShowDialog();
            // ...
        }
```

The problem is I don't know, how to detect, which button was pressed on the frmMain - Save or Cancel. The further logic of the program depends on this fact. I need something like this:

```
private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmSettings = new SettingsForm();
            frmSettings.ShowDialog();

            if(/* frmSettings.SaveButton.WasClicked == true */)
            {
                InitializeServices();
            }
            // ...
        }
```

Please, give me an advice, how to implement such kind of interaction between forms. Better without using global variables for saving buttons state.
Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShowDialog returns a DialogResult object that allow you to know that. You have to:

On Save Button's click event, set `this.DialogResult` to `DialogResult.OK`

On Cancel Button's click event, set `this.DialogResult` to `DialogResult.Cancel`

```
private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmSettings = new SettingsForm();
   if(frmSettings.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       InitializeServices();
   }
   //.......    
}
```

**Edited to manage the DialogResult as @tsiorn's answer: setting form's DialgoResult insted of setting that property on each button.**

Answer (score 1):

You chould use DialogResult to handle this. On your form settings window, you can set the result as so:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    this.close;
}
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    this.close;
}
```

Then ...

```
private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            frmSettings = new SettingsForm(); 
            frmSettings.ShowDialog(); 

            if(frmSettings.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) 
            { 
                // save
                InitializeServices(); 
            } 
            //  ... 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with an enumeration of the possible values:

```
public enum ExitMethod
{
    Other, //this should be first, as a default value
    Save,
    Cancel,
    Error
}
```

Then make a property on `SettingsForm` of that type:

```
public ExitMethod ExitMethod { get; private set; }
```

In SettingsForm's save/exit methods set that property to the appropriate enum value, and in the main form you can read that property value.

Comment: Where I should declare this enum and with which scope? How I'll be able to read ExitMethod value in the main form?

Comment: @SergeyShafiev Just create it as a public enum outside of any class in your namespace; there's not reason for it to not be globally accessible.  You could stick it inside of a class's definition if you really want, but there's no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

in the frmSettings window you handle the Click events on the buttons.  Then set the dialog result:

```
void frmSettings_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

void frmSettings_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

in the main form you do something like this to capture and evaluate the result:

```
DialogResult answer = frmSettings.ShowDialog();
if (answer == DialogResult.OK)
{
  ...
}
```

Additional information and usage can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx